# C++ lnk error 2019 unresolved external symbol virtual errors because of an interface...(?)

Tags: c++, interface, virtual, lnk2019

Im having problems with making a good interface and use it...
My setup overview:

An "interface" **GraphicsLibrary.H**...

```
virtual void drawPoint(const Point& p, unsigned char r, unsigned char g, unsigned char b, double pointSize);
```

with an "empty" GraphicsLibrary.ccp! because its an interface, so "OpenGL" is an graphics library... so i have an **OpenGL.CPP** with:

```
void GraphicsLibrary::drawPoint(const Point& p, unsigned char r, unsigned char g, unsigned char b, double pointSize)
{
    //some code
}
```

which has ofcourse an "empty" OpenGL.h (since his header file is the GraphicsLibrary.h)

then i have a class with more specific functions that uses OpenGL, and uses those base drawing functions... (**OpenGLVis_Enviroment.cpp**):

```
OpenGL ogl;
void drawObstacleUnderConstruction(Obstacle::Type type, const vector<Point>& points)
{
for( //etcetc )
        ogl.drawPoint(*it, 255, 255, 255, 3.0);
}
```

BUT i also have a main that uses some OpenGL functions...
so the **main** has also:

```
OpenGL openGL;
openGL.drawText(something);
```

but now i have a lot of those errors (i have the same with all the other functions):

```
1>OpenGLVis_Environment.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: virtual void __thiscall GraphicsLibrary::drawPoint(struct Point const &,unsigned char,unsigned char,unsigned char,double)" (?drawPoint@GraphicsLibrary@@UAEXABUPoint@@EEEN@Z) referenced in function "void __cdecl DrawingFunctions::drawObstacleUnderConstruction(enum Obstacle::Type,class std::vector<struct Point,class std::allocator<struct Point> > const &)" (?drawObstacleUnderConstruction@DrawingFunctions@@YAXW4Type@Obstacle@@ABV?$vector@UPoint@@V?$allocator@UPoint@@@std@@@std@@@Z)
```

Is this because i use "GraphicsLibrary::drawPoint..." ? I am searching online for ages, but  it's hard to find a lot of examples about interfaces.. and how to work with them... 
Thanks in advance guys

Comment: How are you building your project? What is your IDE?

Comment: the more traditional way of doing interfaces, is to have an abstract base class (`GraphicsLibrary`) which has a pure virtual member function (`GraphicsLibrary::drawPoint`), which can then be implemented by the derived class (`OpenGL`) as `OpenGL::drawPoint`.

Comment: @AndyProwl Im using VS2012, compiling it with that... should i rather use the traditional way of making an interface? (as Sander de Dycker says)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The linker complains about `DrawingFunctions::drawObstacleUnderConstruction` and you defined `void drawObstacleUnderConstruction`, which is a free function.

Qualify the name when you define the function.

```
void DrawingFunctions::drawObstacleUnderConstruction(Obstacle::Type type, const vector<Point>& points)
{
    for( //etcetc )
        ogl.drawPoint(*it, 255, 255, 255, 3.0);
}
```

Comment: Oke now i've done that, but it still doesn't get rid of my error :S